# Pandas merge dataframes and update Only one Column from Second Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, merge, concatenation

I am able to solve the problem, however need a pythonic solution with the following constraints:

The first sample data frame looks like

```
 df1

      A     B      C    D      E      F 

      a    NULL    8    7      uu    qw
      b    hag     9    10     lq    ss
      c    ja     11    2      sa    lo
      d    NULL   17    1      fg
```

The second dataframe looks  like

```
df2   

      A     B      C    D      E      F 

      a    YES     8    7      uu    qw
      b    PLH     9    10     lq    ss
      c    NO     11    2      sa    lo
      e    SAM    17    1      fg
```

So I will like to merge the dataframes on the columns A, C D E & F. However, I will like to replace the Column B with values from second dataframe (df2). So the output should look like:

```
   final_df 


      A     B      C    D      E      F 

      a    YES     8    7      uu    qw
      b    PLH     9    10     lq    ss
      c    NO     11    2      sa    lo
```

I am able to merge the dataframes, however getting two B Columns and have to use drop one B_x column and then rearrange the columns to get the final Dataframe. Is there a better way to do this? The reason I am asking is that I have close to 1000 columns and rearranging the columns is becoming a problem as in that case I have to write all the columns explicitly which is a no-no.

Any help will be appreciated immensely. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why need to merge when the `final_df` is the same to the `df2` except for the last line of the dataframe?

Comment: because the second dataframe column B is the one I need and dont need the ColB from first dataframe

Comment: Do you mind share the approach that u have now. It can help me understand the selection logic

Comment: Is it guaranteed that all columns match across both dataframes?

Comment: yes it is guranteed

Answer (score 0):

If need in ouput same columns like in `df1` with update same columns like `B` in both DataFrames use `suffixes` parameter for add `_` only for column `B` from `df1` and add [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for same order and same columns like in `df1.columns` in output:

```
df = (df1.merge(df2, on=['A','C','D','E', 'F'], suffixes=('_',''))
         .reindex(df1.columns, axis=1))
```